# Issue with dates in a range

Tags: date, sql-server-2008-r2, date-range

Given the following SQL, I have a problem:
Depending on the startdate (@fi) and the enddate (@ff), sometimes returns values, sometimes not.

For example: 
             1)if @fi and @ff are '01/01/2014' -> ok

```
         2)if @fi and @ff are '01/01/2015' -> ok
         3)if @fi and @ff are '31/12/2014' -> no rows
         4)if @fi = '31/12/2014' and @ff = '01/01/2015' -> ok (but returns more rows than the second case, that is, there should be results for the third case).
I've tried with BETWEEN clause, with the same result. I checked (in the 3rd case) if the is included in that range (with an if-else), and yes, it is. Any clue?
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

```
declare @fi date,
    @ff date

    set @fi = '31/12/2014'
    set @ff = '01/01/2015'
SELECT Registro, Area, Grupo, Codigo, Asunto, Año, Total, IdArea, IdGrupo
   FROM
        (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT TM2000_RegistrosAsuntos.Registro,
                TM2000_Areas.Area, TM2000_Grupos.Grupo,
                TM2000_Asuntos.Codigo, TM2000_Asuntos.Asunto,
                SUM(CAST(CASE WHEN FechaDocumento >= @FI
                    AND FechaDocumento <= @FF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    AS integer))
                    AS Año, COUNT(TM2000_RegistroGeneral.Id) AS Total,
                    TM2000_Asuntos.IdArea, TM2000_Asuntos.IdGrupo
             FROM TM2000_RegistroGeneral
             INNER JOIN TM2000_Asuntos ON 
               TM2000_RegistroGeneral.IdAsunto = TM2000_Asuntos.Codigo 
             INNER JOIN 
               TM2000_Areas ON TM2000_Asuntos.IdArea = TM2000_Areas.Id 
             INNER JOIN
               TM2000_Grupos ON TM2000_Asuntos.IdGrupo = TM2000_Grupos.Id AND TM2000_Asuntos.IdArea = TM2000_Grupos.IdArea
             INNER JOIN
               TM2000_RegistrosAsuntos ON TM2000_RegistroGeneral.TipoRegistro = TM2000_RegistrosAsuntos.Id
             WHERE (TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= @FI 
                                    AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= @FF)
                                    AND (ISNULL(TM2000_Asuntos.CodigoNulo, 0) = 0)

                                    OR (TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, @FI)
                                    AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, @FF))
                                    AND (ISNULL(TM2000_Asuntos.CodigoNulo, 0) = 0)

                                    OR (TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= DATEADD(YEAR, - 2, @FI)
                                    AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= DATEADD(YEAR, - 2, @FF))
                                    AND (ISNULL(TM2000_Asuntos.CodigoNulo, 0) = 0)

                                    OR (TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= DATEADD(YEAR, - 3, @FI)
                                    AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= DATEADD(YEAR, - 3, @FF))
                                    AND (ISNULL(TM2000_Asuntos.CodigoNulo, 0) = 0)

                                    OR (TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= DATEADD(YEAR, - 4, @FI)
                                    AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= DATEADD(YEAR, - 4, @FF))
                                    AND (ISNULL(TM2000_Asuntos.CodigoNulo, 0) = 0)
                          GROUP BY TM2000_Asuntos.Asunto, TM2000_Asuntos.IdArea, TM2000_Asuntos.IdGrupo, TM2000_Asuntos.Codigo, TM2000_Areas.Area, TM2000_Grupos.Grupo, 
                                                    TM2000_RegistrosAsuntos.Registro
                          ORDER BY TM2000_RegistrosAsuntos.Registro, TM2000_Asuntos.IdArea, TM2000_Asuntos.IdGrupo) AS TBase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with CAST(DATE, TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento) when comparing at the WHERE clause.

FechaDocumento is a DATETIME, so a cast is needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your where clause with this.

```
  WHERE     (( TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= @fi
              AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= @ff )


        OR ( TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @fi)
                 AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @ff) )

        OR ( TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @fi)
                 AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, @ff) )

        OR ( TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, @fi)
                 AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= DATEADD(YEAR, -3, @ff) )

        OR ( TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento >= DATEADD(YEAR, -4, @fi)
                 AND TM2000_RegistroGeneral.FechaDocumento <= DATEADD(YEAR, -4, @ff) )
            )
            AND ( ISNULL(TM2000_Asuntos.CodigoNulo, 0) = 0 )
```

I believe your OR & AND where fighting with each other and you had the AND clause repeated unnecessarily